# Replicate scrolling style of samsung clock

Tags: android

I'm trying to replicate this style:

[samsung clock app scrolling style](https://streamable.com/6evg5d)

I have tried to implement it as follows:
I have a toolbar view, called "EditableToolbar".
"EditableToolbar" is a custom toolbar I made and it is invisible.
Under it, there is a RecyclerView.
the second item of the recyclerView is an EditableToolbar.

when I scroll the scroll view and the position EditableToolbar of the recycler view is at the top, I set the visibility of the primary EditableToolbar to visible but the transition is not good:

[My implementation](https://streamable.com/9e2016)

MainActivity:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditableToolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/modelsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any suggestions on how to implement it will be great thanks!